# ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`:

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

Why is sess passing into the consumer in training but failing in the eval() in acccracy
https://github.com/JasonPrendergast/AccuracyTestingaModel

I am threading a batch accuracy test and come across the error:  ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default "
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)

I have been using threads for my training and have had no problem passing the session as sess to the consumer class like this:

```
_, c = self.sess.run([self.optimizer, self.cost], feed_dict={x: np.array(batch_x),y: np.array(batch_y)})
```

This is running fine I can produce my model using the consumer class. But when I try running:

```
result = (self.sess.run(tf.argmax(self.prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[np.array(batch_x)]}),1)))
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\jimbob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users\jimbob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>     File "D:/mine/jobs_network/NN_size_10k_batch/testAcc2_threads.py", line 198, in run
>       result = (self.sess.run(tf.argmax(self.prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[np.array(batch_x)]}),1)))
>     File "C:\Users\jimbob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 541, in eval
>       return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
>     File "C:\Users\jimbob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4071, in _eval_using_default_session
>       raise ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default "
>   ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`

Comment: result = (sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[features]}),1))) is working when I am not threading

Answer (score 0):

I have reached the result I wanted by replacing `result = (self.sess.run(tf.argmax(self.prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[np.array(batch_x)]}),1)))`  with
                `result=self.prediction.eval(session = self.sess,feed_dict={x: np.array(batch_x)})
                result= np.array(result)
                outputarray.append(str((labellexicon[int(np.argmax(result))])))`